# How to write file to cassandra from spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and Cassandra. I Use this code but it give me error.

```
val dfprev = df.select(col = "se","hu")
val a = dfprev.select("se")
val b = dfprev.select("hu")
val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(a,b))
collection.saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table", SomeColumns("se","hu"))
```

When I enter this code on `savetocassandra`, it give me error and the error is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple constructors with the same number of parameters not allowed.
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.Reflect$.methodSymbol(Reflect.scala:16)
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.ReflectionUtil$.constructorParams(ReflectionUtil.scala:63)
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DefaultColumnMapper.(DefaultColumnMapper.scala:45) at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.LowPriorityColumnMapper$class.defaultColumnMapper(ColumnMapper.scala:51)
>     at
>   om.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.ColumnMapper$.defaultColumnMapper(ColumnMapper.scala:55)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val dfprev = df.select("se","hu")
dfprev.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options(Map("keyspace"->"YOUR_KEYSPACE_NAME","table"->"YOUR_TABLE_NAME"))
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.save()
```

variable `a` and `b` are of type dataframe. `sc.parallelize` creates a RDD from collection of elements, it doesn't accepts dataframe as input.

**Note:** Set `spark.cassandra.connection.host` AND `spark.cassandra.auth.username` & `spark.cassandra.auth.password` (if authentication is enabled) in `sparkconf`

Comment: There are different saveMode available like Overwrite,Append,ErrorIfExists.. etc... Look at your use case and use appropriate one... with cassandra append will add new record to table and update existing one... if you don't use saveMode and if record with same primary key exists in table then job will fail